# copying to flatfile using vba in excel

Tags: excel, vba, flat-file

I am trying to copy some 2000 rows of data from one Excel file to an Excel-based flatfile. Memory maxes out if I try to copy the whole set at one go, so I tried to copy/paste one row at a time. It takes a considerable amount of time now.
Any workarounds?

I am using Excel 2016 & 32-bit system. I can't move this to 64-bit, since the other users may not have access to 64-bit system.

here's the code used

```
        'run loop from first row to last filled row, check if flag is yes, then copy entire row
        For RowCount = 1 To RowMax
        Indicator = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Summary View").Cells(RowCount, 10).Value

            If Indicator = "Yes" Then

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Summary View").Cells(RowCount, 10).EntireRow.Copy
                DestWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCountP, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                RowCountP = RowCountP + 1

            ElseIf Indicator = "SupplyRisk Indicator" Then

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Summary View").Cells(RowCount, 10).EntireRow.Copy
                DestWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCountP, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                RowCountP = RowCountP + 1

            End If
```

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: I don't think having to use 32 bits for backwards compatibility is likely to be the issue, but if it is then you should look into [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/directives).